# Cookie not getting set in browser via spring rest redirect api in httpserveletrresponse in client browser

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets, cookies

I'm trying to set cookie in client browser while redirecting from my Spring rest api controller to app home page (hosted somewhere else) by specifying URI of home page.
But it seems cookie coming in response headers but not getting set in cookie database.

and here are the values of domain and path;

```
domain = localhost
path = /
isSecure = false/true based on env.
```

I've tried lot of things to make it work, few of them are below;

1. domain = localhost:8080 [ as my ui code running on 8080 port ]
2. domain = < ip >:8080
3. domain = xyz.com [ i've mention an entry in my host file with 127.0.0.1:8080 xyz.com

Any one pls help, its been stuck quite a while.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ResponseEntity<?> ssoLoginAndFetchUserInfo(@RequestParam(value = "code", required = true) String code,
        @RequestParam(value = "state", required = true) String state, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
      normalLog.info("sso/login api invoked with code {} and state {}", code, state);
    final SSOUserInfoHostInfoWrapper info = ssoServices.ssoFetchUserInformation(code, state);
    normalLog.info("info fetched {}", info);

    response.addCookie(CommonUtil.createCookie(SSOContants.UserInfoConstants.IDENTITY_TOKEN,
        info.getUserInfo().getTokenInfo().getId_token(), info.getHostInfo().getHostname(),
        info.getUserInfo().getTokenInfo().getExpires_in(), IDENTITY_COOKIE_NAME, "/",
        info.getHostInfo().isSecure()));

    response.addCookie(
        CommonUtil.createCookie(SSOContants.UserInfoConstants.USER_NAME, info.getUserInfo().getUserName(),
            info.getHostInfo().getHostname(), info.getUserInfo().getTokenInfo().getExpires_in(),
            USERNAME_COOKIE_NAME, "/", info.getHostInfo().isSecure()));

    response.addCookie(
        CommonUtil.createCookie(SSOContants.UserInfoConstants.USER_ID, info.getUserInfo().getUserId(),
            info.getHostInfo().getHostname(), info.getUserInfo().getTokenInfo().getExpires_in(),
            USERNAME_COOKIE_ID, "/", info.getHostInfo().isSecure()));

    response.addCookie(
        CommonUtil.createCookie("authentication_token", "sdfsdfsdf",
            info.getHostInfo().getHostname(), info.getUserInfo().getTokenInfo().getExpires_in(),
            "authentication_token", "/", info.getHostInfo().isSecure()));

    // Redirect to app login page
    response.setHeader("Location", info.getHostInfo().getAppHomePageURI());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FOUND);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return super.returnSpringError(e);
    }
}
```

Utility method

```
public static Cookie createCookie(final String name, final String value, final String hostname, final int expiresIn,
        final String comment, final String validToPath, final boolean isSecure) {
    Cookie c = new Cookie(name, value);
    c.setPath(validToPath);
    c.setDomain(hostname);
    c.setVersion(1);
    c.setComment(comment);
    c.setMaxAge(expiresIn);
    c.setSecure(isSecure);

    return c;

}
```

Few screenshots for what is heapping ;
[image: Cookie database]

Comment: Why are you mixing Jersey and Spring MVC annotations... Start with fixing that.

Comment: Ya, its already been fixed actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed. From the day one i doubt its all due to "domain".
Don't know yet why putting "localhost" in domain does not working, probably DNS not getting resolved.

Here how i resolved it;
I made an entry in /etc/hosts file with below entry 
127.0.0.1       xx.yy.zz-r.com

And then use domain as ".zz-r.com" and access all the ui page via 
xx.yy.zz-r.com:8080/----------

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same problem. My case was to pass redirect from backend to frontend with attached cookies. Within one main domain. There's no success with code

```
cookie.path = "/"
cookie.domain = "domain.com"
cookie.maxAge = 60
cookie.isHttpOnly = false
response.addCookie(cookie)
```

But everything run when I changed to

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "customCookie=value; Path=/; Max-Age=60; Domain=domain.com")
```